# JS form validate is getting stuck after incorrect input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement form validation for a 'confirm password' field, but it's being extremely difficult. I've got an `onsubmit="validate()` attribute on my form, and that's calling the below JavaScript fine, but if I enter the incorrect details, there are two issues which I can't seem to fix:

a) The message doesn't appear unless I click 'Submit' again

b) When I rectify the confirm password box, it still displays the message

My code is below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login or Register";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Login or Register</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required placeholder="Username..." />
            <br />
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required placeholder="Password..." />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login!" />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <form id="registerForm" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="/Account/RegisterAccount">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" tabindex="1" required placeholder="First Name..." />
                    <br />
                    <input id="password0" data-minlength="6" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" tabindex="3" min="6" required placeholder="Password..." />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" tabindex="2" required placeholder="Last Name..." />
                    <br />
                    <input id="password1" data-match="#password0" type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" tabindex="4" required placeholder="Confirm Password..." />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100% !important;" class="form-control" name="username" tabindex="5" required placeholder="Username..." />
                    <br />
                    <input type="email" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100% !important;" class="form-control" name="email" tabindex="6" required placeholder="Email..." />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input id="registerButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register!" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function validate() {
        debugger;
        if ($('#password0').val() != $('#password1').val()) {
            document.getElementById("password1").setCustomValidity("These passwords don't match!");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("password1").setCustomValidity("");
        }
        return document.getElementById('password1').checkValidity();

    }
</script>
```

UPDATE:

I've just published the recent version, it's at [roconnor.somee.com/oas](http://roconnor.somee.com/oas)

Comment: Are you getting any error in your `browser console` ?

Comment: @M.Tanzil No, but I just noticed something extremely weird, the function isn't even being hit...

Comment: have you tried another method of calling? 
`$('form').submit(validate);`

Comment: @JacobGoh where would that go sorry?

Comment: `$('form').submit(validate);` is jquery's way of detecting form submit. Try removing `onsubmit="validate()` and add `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('form').submit(validate); });</script>` to footer. See if the function is being hit or not.

Comment: Provide your html code so that we have a look.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Please see the updated question

Comment: Did anyone else see that crazy Angular answer?